Type safe navigation: Starting destination with argument
At one point in my app I want to navigate to a nested graph that's starting destination requires an ID from the previous screen, but I get an error:
kotlinx.serialization.SerializationException: Serializer for class 'Companion' is not found.  
                                                                                                Please ensure that class is marked as '@Serializable' and that the serialization compiler plugin is applied.

The Graph:
@Serializable
data object MainScreen {

    @Serializable
    data class MainScreenFirstScreen(val id: Int)
}

The Navigation:
            onNavigateToNextScreen = { id ->
                navHostController.navigate(
                    route = OwnerGraph.MainScreen.MainScreenFirstScreen(
                        id = id
                    )
                )

The NavGraph
fun NavGraphBuilder.mainScreenOwnerNavGraph(
    navHostController: NavHostController,
) {
    navigation<OwnerGraph.MainScreen>(
        startDestination = OwnerGraph.MainScreen.MainScreenFirstScreen
    ) {
        composable<OwnerGraph.MainScreen.MainScreenFirstScreen> { navBackStackEntry ->
            Text("Main Screen")
        }
    }
}


I recommend that you edit your question to provide more of the stack trace, not just the error line.

OwnerGraph.MainScreen.MainScreenFirstScreen requires an Int parameter that you forgot to specify when assigning it to startDestination.

You have to pass either argument or default value in route. If you just want to ignore passing arguments in OwnerGraph.MainScreen.MainScreenFirstScreen modify your routes like below,
Add default value,
@Serializable
data object MainScreen {

    @Serializable
    data class MainScreenFirstScreen(val id: Int= -1) // Added default value
}

The in your navgraph builder add constructor to ignore passing arguments         startDestination = OwnerGraph.MainScreen.MainScreenFirstScreen()
fun NavGraphBuilder.mainScreenOwnerNavGraph(
    navHostController: NavHostController,
) {
    navigation<OwnerGraph.MainScreen>(
        startDestination = OwnerGraph.MainScreen.MainScreenFirstScreen()
    ) {
        composable<OwnerGraph.MainScreen.MainScreenFirstScreen> { navBackStackEntry ->
            Text("Main Screen")
        }
    }
}

